# Cannot use Margin "Thickness" value

Tags: c#, winforms, margin, thickness

Using Visual Studio C#: I am trying to dynamically add some PictureBoxes to a TableLayoutPanel called "MapGrid".

As far as my Googling can tell, this:

```
MapGrid.Controls.Add(new PictureBox() 
            { 
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill, 
                Margin = new Thickness(0)
            });
```

should work.  The "Dock" part works, but I need to set all the margins to 0 and I am getting:

```
The type or namespace name 'Thickness' could not be found
```

Answer (score 4):

Windows Forms [`PictureBox.Margin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.margin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a [`Padding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.padding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not a `Thickness`.

```
MapGrid.Controls.Add(new PictureBox 
                         { 
                             Dock = DockStyle.Fill, 
                             Margin = new Padding(0)
                         });
```

The [`Thickness`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type is for WPF, and not used in Windows Forms controls.

Answer (score 1):

For winforms, the `Margin` is of type `Padding`, not `Thickness`.  Try:

```
MapGrid.Controls.Add(new PictureBox() { 
                                      Dock = DockStyle.Fill, 
                                      Margin = new Padding(0)
                                      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the documentation, `Thickness` isn't the class you need. Try using `Padding` instead:

[Control.Margin Property - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.margin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)